# Can't set code of ng-ace-editor from an Observable

Tags: angular, ace-editor

I'm having trouble with populating [ng2-ace-editor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-ace-editor) text from an Observable (`from` and `delay` supposed to mimic a future service).

**page.component.html:**

```
<ace-editor #editor
    style="height:350px;"
    [text]="code"
    [mode]="'html'"
    [theme]="'clouds'"
    [readOnly]="false"
    [autoUpdateContent]="true"
></ace-editor>
```

**page.component.ts:**

```
export class PageComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
    code: string = '';
    editorOptions: any = {
        showPrintMargin: false,
        showInvisibles: true,
        highlightGutterLine: true,
    };

    @ViewChild('editor') editor;

    ngOnInit() {
        this._dummyGetUserHtml().subscribe(data => {
            this.code = data; // why won't this work?
            this.editor.getEditor().setValue(data); // and we need this?
            console.log('code', data);
        });
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.editor.getEditor().setOptions(this.editorOptions);
    }

    private _dummyGetUserHtml(){
        return Observable.from([
            `<body><p>Hello world!</p></body>`
        ]).delay(1000);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? (The thing does not work also when I move the subscription to `ngAfterViewInit`)

I mean: I know instead of: `this.code = data` I could do `this.editor.getEditor().setValue(data)`, but since the package instructions say the component accepts `text` as `@Input`, I expect that my original code should work without using the api methods.

Comment: I don't get what the problem is. Your code doesn't contain `this.text = data` that you mention in the text.

Comment: It an obvious typo. I wrote this piece off the top of my head. It should be `this.code = data` - fixing my post.

Comment: I still don't get what the actual problem is.

Comment: The `ace-editor` accepts a `[text]` input. This means, that by saying `[text]="code"` in the html, we should have the editor update its text whenever `this.code = ...` assigns a new value. This does not happen. I have to resort to ace editor api method `.setValue(data)`. I just don't get it.

Comment: Seems to be an `<ace-editor>` issue. Perhaps it ignores changes after the initialization.

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer. Still fresh on ng2 and so sometimes unsure if doing/expecting things the right way.